# Serving static files for golang in docker-container using echo middleware

Tags: docker, go, static, echo, middleware

So. I have a stucture like this:

app
-api
-templates
-examples
-html

using echo like this

```
e.Use(middleware.StaticWithConfig(middleware.StaticConfig{
        Root:       "examples/html",
        Browse:     true,
        IgnoreBase: true,
    }))
```

and it works perfect when I run it locally

but when i put this in docker-container
then i get error trying to get fonts and other params for page

```
2023-05-03T19:14:48Z ERR error="code=400, message=failed to parse page id: invalid UUID length: 16" environment=dev latency=0 method=GET path=/i/blocks/index.css query= version=v0.0.0
```

/i/ - is the group path in api
locally it gets handled by  IgnoreBase: true in middleware.StaticConfig above

not so in docker

here's part of the docker file after build:

```
RUN go build myApp

FROM debian:buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY templates/ templates/
COPY examples/html/ examples/html/
COPY --from=build_stage /app/app-server /app/app-server

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/app-server"]
```

everything else works perfect, it sees templates, gets info from them, but fails to get statics from examples/html

P>S> would be perfect if solution uses go:embed, but just making it run properly would be great enough )))

P>P>S>
There is a template that contains `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./blocks/index.css">`
to get the page I call Get `http://localhost:8080/i/:id`
through middleware it should call `examples/html/blocks/index.css`
but instead it calls to `/i/blocks/index.css`

as mentioned above it works perfect when i run the app locally, but when it is in a container it fails with mistake above, because middleware doesn't remove junk from the path like it does when run locally.

UPD: it stopped working locally too. Now I don't understand anything.

Comment: Try to put absolute paths into you dockerfile

Comment: This error `code=400, failed to parse page id: invalid UUID length: 16` doesn't look like a static route issue. The error is 400, not 404. I tested here and Dockerfile is copying all directory nodes. Can you add more info to your question on how you're hitting the API and if any UUID is being used?

Comment: yes it seems that everything is alright with docker paths, i tried to copy like this before ```#COPY --from=build_stage /dp/templates /dp/templates
#COPY --from=build_stage /dp/examples/html /dp/examples/html ``` Doesn't work either. As for path. There should not be any uuid for static. Basicly what this does   IgnoreBase: true, it removes junk from path(/i/ in this case). So the path it looks at is examples/html/blocks/index.css at least it does locally. But in docker-container it doesn't remove it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, it seems like the issue might be related to the path resolution in the Docker container. Let's try to fix it by using the absolute path for the Root configuration in the middleware.StaticConfig:

1. Modify your main.go to include the embed package and use the embed.FS to serve your static files:

```
package main

import (
    _ "embed"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

//go:embed examples/html
var html embed.FS

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    absPath, _ := filepath.Abs("examples/html")
    e.Use(middleware.StaticWithConfig(middleware.StaticConfig{
        Root:       absPath,
        Filesystem: http.FS(html),
        Browse:     true,
        IgnoreBase: true,
    }))

    // Other routes and middlewares

    e.Start(":8080")
}
```

2. Modify your Dockerfile to include the necessary files:

```
# Build stage
FROM golang:1.17 as build_stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -o app-server .

# Final stage
FROM debian:buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY templates/ templates/
COPY examples/html/ examples/html/
COPY --from=build_stage /app/app-server /app/app-server

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/app-server"]
```

With these changes, your application should be able to serve the static files correctly when running inside a Docker container.

This solution uses the embed package and the http.FS for serving static files. It also makes sure that the absolute path is used for the Root configuration in the middleware.StaticConfig.

Comment: Tried locally. Added abs. Embed i'm using like so     package app

import (
 "embed"
)

//go:embed examples/html
var StaticFiles embed.FS
and then Filesystem: http.FS(app.StaticFiles) in middleware; what surprises me the most that it stopped working locally too, it definetly did before and nothing was changed other then dockerfile (

Answer (score 0):

Closing this issue. My guess there was a problem in cache or smth. Because through middleware it doesn't work locally either.

It works like this

```
e := echo.New()
e.Static("/i/blocks", "examples/html/blocks")
e.Static("/i/assets", "examples/html/assets")
e.Static("/i/blocks/body/examples/html/assets", "examples/html/assets")
e.Static("/i/blocks/logo/examples/html/assets", "examples/html/assets")
```

both locally and through container
will post separate question on how to make it look good